# What is preventing Javascript from execution?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Neither of the Javascript function is executed in "btnrepeat()", although I have called another javascript in page_load event and that is working fine

C#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Timer1.Enabled = true;
     workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(btnrepeat));
     workerThread.Start();
}

protected void btnrepeat()
{
     ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "mys", "abcd()", true);

     for (int i = 1; i <= filecount; i++)
     {
          string trnsfrpth = @"E:\\ProjectLocalPath\" + filename;
          last_file++;
          balance_load(filename, trnsfrpth);
          Thread.Sleep(200);
     }

     ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "mytts", "abcd()", true);
     //Label1.InnerHtml = last_file.ToString();     
     //This is not aspx label, but an HTML div
     //this is possible actually but not working here
}
```

Javascript

```
function abcd() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

Function is doing what it is supposed to, so there is no logical mistake.

And I've also tried,

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "mytts", "abcd()", true);

And The last 3 lines commented is another problem, it doesn't work...why ?

Comment: It does not work because the completed html page is already send to the client when `btnrepeat` is finished because you started it in a different thread. That is also why `Label1` is not updated. Threading works different in IIS than in a "normal" windows program.

Comment: @VDWWD what is the solution ?